# Black screen at boot time after a kernel update/upgrade or a clean install

Tags: kernel, boot, system-installation, opensuse, graphics

Yo there, I have been experiencing a black screen problem after a clean install, an update of the kernel or upgrade of the distribution (opensuse tumbleweed). Recently what it struck the issue was a mismatch on the kernel(6.4.9-1.1) installed and the headers/devel(6.5.4-1.1) , so installed the latest kernel and reboot but it gets a black screens and does not start the graphical target and seems to randomly load/no load the drivers of the devices.
then added the `nomodeset` to kernel boot options (be at boot time or `/boot/grub.conf`), and the same; the next options were used in the same fashion

```
radeon.si_support=0 radeon.cik_support=0 amdgpu.si_support=1 amdgpu.cik_support=1 amdgpu.dc=1 amdgpu.dpm=1 amdgpu.modeset=1  fbcon=map:1
```

But it does not makes any difference. There is something strange when booting the latest kernel since it seemed to be frozen in boot but after a time, started to report the absence of the devices used in `/boot` and `/`, but this is funny since these devices are physically in the system. I don't know why the system does not found them.
Another funny thing is in a prior upgrade try, booted, get the black screen and opening another tty terminal I logged in as root and could start a mate environment but with limited functionality, no wifi, no ethernet and the like; when trying to boot as the old runlevel 3 or 4 via

```
linuxefi ..... 3
```

or

```
linuxefi ..... 4
```

in order to use yast to pindown the failure(s) the proper r8169 driver does not load and the computer is left without lan service the system, (only with a interface br0, but I wonder which one is, and it didn't work either).
Checked

```
/var/log/Xorg.0.log
/home/user/.xsessions-errors
```

and the output of `dmesg` , but there is nothing relevant, to me at least, in it.

in https://forums.opensuse.org/t/boot-to-black-screen/138390/10
it is suggested a framebuffer problem but I'm using the same option when booting and it has no effect.
There is the same error in a couple of machines with similar specs, all uses the `amdgpu` driver.
A workaround that used to work (or work randomly) is to add the repo:

```
http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/X11:/XOrg/
```

and switch the `X11` and `xorg` rpms to it, but it didn't work lately.
I'm using `X11` and `GDM`, but switching to `SDDM` and other display managers don't work too.
User autologin it's enabled, testing the same machine with another distro (Debian 12.1) does not show the issue.
Thanks for your kind attention.

PD. A thing done lately, but only in one of the systems is to disable completely the swap partition, removing the UUID from `/etc/fstab` and rebuild the init image.

Comment: I currently see the same problem on my Tumbleweed. I tried also `rd. plymouth=0 plymouth.enable=0 plymouth=0`, so [Pplymouth](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Plymouth/) is disabled, but black screen continues. Also `init=/bin/bash` has black screen. Live USB show it works. In my case it's Nvidia + Intel GPU.

Comment: I wonder if it can be somehow affected by https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=ca62297b2085b5b3168bd891ca24862242c635a1 still not being reverted, as mentioned in https://bugzilla.suse.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1213693#c14.

Comment: I haven't checked the bug as noted by @pevik, but I'm certain the problem lies somewhere out of the boot process, this has to do with the kernel itself.

Comment: Live media seems to work, but when doing a install it gets the same error.